# Memory Profiler tool to get an estimation of improvement enabling NUMA

Tags: low-latency, memory-profiling, numa

I work on a low latency application that in my opinion would greatly benefit from the enabling of NUMA (or improving the memory locality anyway).

Is there a profiling tool that would give me an estimation on what could be the improvement, maybe in terms of percent/factor of reduction of execution time?

I was considering using cachegrind. I would expect a lot of LL cache miss, but still I wouldn't have an idea of the expected improvement.

Thanks a lot.

Edit:
The goal here is trying to reduce the latency. Currently, there is a thread that works on startup and do all the allocations. A better implementation, I believe, would be to pin the threads to cpu cores, and make every threads to make the allocation it needs. Before to do that i'd like to have, somehow, an estimation of the benefit in terms of latency.

Comment: You might need to add more information to get a useful answer. Memory locality, in general, benefits _every_ non-trivial application, and there is nothing to "enable" for NUMA (either the hardware is or is not NUMA). The system libs are normally intelligent enough to not needlessly create threads or do allocations on the wrong side, so unless you do that deliberately or have several processes, there's not much to do. If, for some reason, a thread gets bumbed over, there's not much you can do either, anyway. So, exactly what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to reduce the latency. Currently, there is a thread that works on startup and do all the allocations. A better implementation, I believe, would be to pin the threads to cpu cores, and make every threads to make the allocation it needs. Before to do that i'd like to have, somehow, an estimation of the benefit in terms of latency.

Comment: Profilers don't estimate things, they measure. It's unclear why you'd want something to estimate benefits for you, instead of just doing what you think would improve things and measuring that to see if it actually would. If it's too much work up front, you can still measure a toy scenario that resembles the work you're doing -- estimating the latency of your requests can just be done by wall clock time, albeit with precise timestamps. This toy scenario could still be wildly wrong compared to the real thing, but it beats armchair estimations.

Comment: Great suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Pinning threads can be a good, and it can be a bad. The OS will normally try moderately hard to migrate a thread at all, and _very_ hard not to bump it onto the wrong NUMA side (so pinning has little, or zero effect). On the other hand, if no "good" core is available, the only alternative is to not run the thread at all. In some situations you can guarantee that this isn't happening, but if you can't, then pinning is a really stupid idea. A profiler can't help there, though. Allocating all memory in _one_ thread is almost certainly a bad idea if you consider NUMA (unless you explicitly choose)